# Tools required to burn code in a quad flat microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I always have a doubt that how do firmware engineers dump code into a quad flat microcontroller(with or without leads)? For a starter kit there is already connection like USB or some SPI ,I2C headers to burn the code. I know that for Dual inline Package there are some programmers in the market.Then what about quad flat micros used in industrial application?How do you all proceed?

Comment: @Jeroen Well the answers were concentrated on mass production but not considering a hobbyist or a firmware consultant.

Answer (score 2):

Either add an in-system programming interface (e.g. header pins, or some kind of pad for a programming jig),

OR get the manufacturer of the device to factory program the devices before they're installed in the circuit. This is a service which is typically offered by the manufacturers - they must have some kind of test / programming rig in the factory, but they would probably need that anyway because I am guessing that most microcontrollers, even re-flashable ones, need some one-time programming (e.g. maybe calibration data or serial numbers etc) anyway.

I've been making very small volumes, so I have an in-circuit programming connector on my boards, and I manually program them

Answer (score 0):

> quad flat micros

There are (rather expensive) debug adapters for (L)QFP packages.

But it is *much* simpler to just include a debug socket in the PCB design. Flashing firware is one step in the fished PCB testing process.